# Is there a constant we can pick that will make this function holmomorphic on the disc of radius 2?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given a function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^5 -2z^4 +z^2+18z-40}-\frac{k}{z-2}$ is there a way we can find a constant $k$ that will make this function holmomorphic on an open set containing the disc $\{z:z \leq 2\}$ ?

My thoughts so far are as follows:

We can factor the first fraction and use partial fraction decomposition to get the expression $\frac{1}{38(z-2)}+\frac{-z^3 -9-2z^2-4z}{38(z^4 +z+20)}-\frac{k}{z-2}$.

So if we take $k=\frac{1}{38}$ then the first and last fractions cancel out leaving us with $f(z)= \frac{-z^3 -9-2z^2-4z}{38(z^4 +z+20)}$.

Using Roché Theorem we can show that the denominator of this function does not have any zeros in the disc ${z:z \leq 2}$. Is this enough to prove that it will be holmomorphic on an open set containing the disc $\{z:z \leq 2\}$ ? Showing this holds on an open set containing this disc is worrying me. I know that on the disc itself it will not have zeros but I'm not sure how to extend this to an open set containing the disc.

Comment: You don't need Rouché's theorem: $|z^4 +z+20| \ge 20 - |z|^4 - |z| \ge 2 > 0$ if $|z| \le 2$.

Comment: @ Martin R interesting way to show it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The denominator is a polynomial, so it has finitely many zeros, one of which must have the smallest absolute value $a$. You've showed that $a > 2$, so the open disk of radius $a$ is an open set which contains the closed disk of radius $2$ and does not contain any zeros of the denominator.

Comment: thank you! I knew I was close to completing the proof and that really helped fill in the missing blanks I needed.